# APF strangely blocks 443 port with specific time interval

Tags: centos, ssl, firewall, https

I run on CentOS cloud server. Recently I installed SSL and enabled https for my site. After enabling https every 20-24 hours APF blocks 443 port but 80 is accessible as usual. After I restart APF 443 can be accessible for another 20-24 hours.  443 port is enabled in the APF config.  Any help or direction highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell, APF is abandoned. It hasn't had an update of any sort in two years, and its author hasn't been heard from in even longer than that. Consider using firewalld; it came with CentOS and is actually maintained and supported.

Comment: I have seen this on a few servers (we run somewhere around a hundred with `apf`) and it seems to be an issue on the upstream router or firewall. As you say, reloading `apf` restores the connection. It can also often be reset by sending a arp ping to the upstream router.

Comment: @MichaelHampton last I heard it was being redesigned to work with firewalld, and that should be what is used on CentOS 7.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, firewalld seems one of the reliable choices. For the time being I stopped APF and will somehow use iptables. But can I install firewalld on CentOS 6.x ? So far I could not find a way to install it on CentOS 6.x.  All instructions require me to have CentOS 7.